# How to make a turtle bounce off walls

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have to write a code for a computer science class that makes a turtle bounce around a rectangle, and also changes color every time it does this. What I tried to do was divide the rectangle into 4 sections based on the degree its setheading is, but that doesn't seem to be working I'm a beginner, and I've been trying to figure this out for a while. I'm completely lost, so any advice/help would be much appreciated.

```
import turtle, random

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
t.pensize(5)
t.color("Black")


def Rectangle():
  for i in range(2):
    t.forward(400)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.left(90)

Rectangle()


t.penup()
t.goto(205,100)
t.color("Blue")
t.shape("circle")


direct = random.randint(1,360)

def tDirection(direct):
  t.right(direct)

tDirection(direct)



while True:

  color = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', "purple", "pink", "turquoise"]

  t.forward(2)
  ty = t.ycor()
  tx = t.xcor()

  #breaking out bottom
  if ty < 9:
    t.color((random.choice(color)))
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(270>angleCurr>180):
      t.left(90)
    if(270<angleCurr<360):
      t.right(90)
    t.forward(2)

  #breaking out top
  if ty > 188:
    t.color((random.choice(color)))
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(0<angleCurr<90):
      t.right(90)  
    elif(90<angleCurr<180):
      t.left(90)
    t.forward(2)

  #breaking out left
  if tx < 11:
    t.color((random.choice(color)))
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(180<angleCurr<270):
      t.right(90)  
    elif(270<angleCurr<180):
      t.left(90)
    t.forward(2)

  #breaking out right
  if tx > 390:
    t.color((random.choice(color)))
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(0<angleCurr<90):
      t.left(90)  
    elif(0<angleCurr<-90):
      t.right(90)
    t.forward(2)
```

Comment: Hi Sophia, what exactly do you mean it isnt working? what are you seeing? Also, I would suggest simplifying the code. Instead of comparing individually of x and y, cant you make it a Point(x,y) and compare it that way?

Answer (score 0):

You make some mistakes in angle direction change, when you have to set **angle right +90** you set **angle left +90** or when you have to set **angle left +90** you set **angle right +90** in **left, right and bottom wall collision**.

Sometimes when turtle change color random.choice(color) turns the color into the same as it is. I make better code for changing the color so you always change color for turtle.

```
import turtle, random

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
t.pensize(5)
t.color("Black")


def Rectangle():
  for i in range(2):
    t.forward(400)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.left(90)

Rectangle()


t.penup()
t.goto(205,100)
t.color("Blue")
t.shape("circle")

A = random.randint(30,60)
B = random.randint(120,150)
C = random.randint(210,240)
D = random.randint(300,330)
Directions = [A, B, C, D]
direct = random.choice(Directions)

def tDirection(direct):
  t.right(direct)

tDirection(direct)


speed = 2
angle = 90
while True:

  color = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', "purple", "pink", "turquoise"]

  t.forward(speed)
  ty = t.ycor()
  tx = t.xcor()

  #print(ty, tx)

  #breaking out bottom
  if ty < 9:
    Col = random.choice(color)
    while Col == t.color()[0]:
      Col = random.choice(color)
    t.color(Col)
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(270>angleCurr>180):
      t.right(angle)
    else:
      t.left(angle)

    t.forward(2)

  #breaking out top
  if ty > 188:
    Col = random.choice(color)
    while Col == t.color()[0]:
      Col = random.choice(color)
    t.color(Col)
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(0<angleCurr<90):
      t.right(angle)
    else:
      t.left(angle)

    t.forward(2)

  #breaking out left
  if tx < 11:
    Col = random.choice(color)
    while Col == t.color()[0]:
      Col = random.choice(color)
    t.color(Col)
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(180<angleCurr<270):
      t.left(angle)
    else:
      t.right(angle)

    t.forward(2)

  #breaking out right
  if tx > 390:
    Col = random.choice(color)
    while Col == t.color()[0]:
      Col = random.choice(color)
    t.color(Col)
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(0<angleCurr<90):
      t.left(angle)
    else:
      t.right(angle)

    t.forward(speed)
```

Comment: The OP's code allowed for a random starting angle from 1 to 360 degrees but your implementation reduces potential starting angles to 1/3 of that, and can fail if allowed a full range.   Could you add a discussion of this to your answer, as to why it's called for and how your logic ensures those other angles will never be achieved in the course of bouncing?  It seems to be the heart of your solution.

Comment: My logic ensure those other angles will never be achieved in the course of bouncing because turtle always change angle for 90 degrees. When turtle have random angle from 1 to 360 degrees he sometimes hit the wall, change angle and color but the angle is almost parallel to the wall which makes it fall out of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can fix your program and simplify it.  And *parameterize* it so you can change your rectangle size and stil have it work without fixing up lots of lines of code.  And center it on the screen:

```
from turtle import Turtle
from random import randint

COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', "purple", "pink", "turquoise"]

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 200

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def Rectangle():
    t.pendown()

    for i in range(2):
        t.forward(WIDTH)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(HEIGHT)
        t.left(90)

    t.penup()

def tDirection(direct):
    t.setheading(direct)

t = Turtle("circle", visible=False)
t.speed('fastest')
t.pensize(5)
t.penup()
t.goto(-WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/2)

Rectangle()

index = 0

t.color(COLORS[index % len(COLORS)])
t.home()
t.showturtle()

direct = randint(1, 360)

tDirection(direct)

while True:
    t.forward(2)
    ty = t.ycor()

    # breaking out top or bottom
    if not CURSOR_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2 <= ty <= HEIGHT/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2:
        index += 1
        t.color(COLORS[index % len(COLORS)])

        angleCurr = t.heading()

        if 0 < angleCurr < 180:
            tDirection(0 - angleCurr)
        else:
            tDirection(360 - angleCurr)

        t.forward(2)

    tx = t.xcor()

    # breaking out left or right
    if not CURSOR_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2 <= tx <= WIDTH/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2:
        index += 1
        t.color(COLORS[index % len(COLORS)])

        angleCurr = t.heading()

        if 0 < angleCurr < 180:
            tDirection(180 - angleCurr)
        else:
            tDirection(540 - angleCurr)

        t.forward(2)
```

You'll notice I changed it from using *left* and *right* 90 degree turns to using absolute headings to control the ball bouncing off the walls.  And made the color advance through the list of colors (in a circular fashion) instead of choosing one (possibly the same one) at random.